# Temperature to make oceans evaporate

Tags: evaporation

The Boiling point of the water is 100 C after that water evaporates. If we are to heat the water of all the oceans combined, what should the temperature be set at, so that all the water gets evaporated?

Comment: Do you want to know the temperature to make seawater evaporate, or to boil? They're different things.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I want to know the temperature to make seawater evaporates..

Comment: It will evaporate at any temperature. However, remember, evaporation only occurs at the surface of the liquid.

Answer (score 2):

The boiling point of saturated saline solution [is around 108.7°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride#Aqueous_solutions), so you need a temperature at least as high as this.

I wonder if you are mixing up the temperature required with the amount of energy required. As long as we keep the temperature above the boiling point we can evaporate an arbitrarily large amount of water, but of course it will require an arbitrarily large amount of energy to keep the temperature at this level.

Answer (score 2):

Water evaporates at all temperatures above freezing point, but weather condenses it back into rain, which finds its way back into the oceans.

If atmospheric water was lost into space, at a greater rate than cosmic water entered the Earth's atmosphere, after sufficient undetermined time, all the ocean's waters may be lost.

Answer (score 2):

When pure liquid water is left in the open, some of it will evaporate, even if it's not boiling. Evaporated water (vapour) builds up in the atmosphere until an equlibrium is reached between the rate of evaporation (liquid -> vapour) and the rate of condensation (vapour -> liquid). The pressure of water vapour in the atmosphere is known as the 'vapour pressure' of water (at that temperature).

Generally, the vapour pressure increases (non-linearly) with temperature.

The water 'boils' is when the vapour pressure equals the surrounding environmental pressure. The 'normal boiling point' of water is the temperature at which the vapour pressure of water equals the surrounding environmental pressure at sea level (1 atm), which, as it turns out, is closer to $99.974^o C$ not $100^o C$, despite the 'original definition' of the Celsius scale being based on 100 equal 'degrees' between the freezing point of water (set to $0^o C$)and the boiling point of water (set to $100^o C$) at sea level (1 atm). The [reason for the discrepancy](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/sts/staff/chang/boiling/index.htm) is quite long winded and sheds some interesting light on the philosophy of science and how concepts in science are measured.

Now, getting back to the question, the presence of non-volatile compounds dissolved in seawater have a tendancy to lower the vapour pressure. That is, the less of the water will evaporate off at a given temperature, because the non-volatile dissolved solids (salts) in seawater are strongly ionic and have a tendancy to 'hold onto' the water in the liquid. The net effect is that a higher temperature will be reached before the vapour pressure of sea water equals the surrounding atmospheric pressure (1 atm). This increase in boiling point temperature over that of pure water is called the **Boiling Point Elevation (BPE)** of sea water (at that temperature and salinity, S).

[image]

If you were to increase the temperature of the oceans to the *elevated boiling temperatures*, then as the fresh water in the oceans boiled off, the salinity of the remaining water would increase. This increase in relative concentration of non-volatiles (salt) with respect to water molecules leads to a drop in the vapour pressure and a *further increase in the boiling temperature*.

Also, as the level of the oceans dropped due to evaporation, the *surrounding atmospheric pressure would also increase*, as too the boiling point of the ocean.

The combined effect of decrease vapour pressure and increased atmospheric pressure means the temperature at which the water had to be maintained to boil the remaining seawater would go up markedly as the oceans evaporated.

Finally, as the last of the water begins to evaporate, the hygroscopic ionic salts start to form crystals and 'fight' strongly to retain the last of the water molecules within their crystalline structure. Up to 15% of the mass of 'dry' sea salt remaining at the bottom of the ocean floor would contain bound water molecules in hydrates. Further energy (and higher temperatures) would be required to dehydrate the crystal salts into anhydrous form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not at expert and also am new so my answer could be unsatisfying or wrong. But here I go:

The temperature should be around 99.97 C for the water to boil. To boil all the water and evaporate the water in all the oceans, the same temperature of 99.97 C could work if the equal amount of heat is applied to all the molecules. That is, if each molecule is provided heat equivalent to 100 C the water will evaporate. No need to provide extra temperature. It will boil anyway.

Comment: not satisfied.. I dont think this will evaporate all the water of the oceans..

Answer (score 0):

Water has an interesting property in which on being heated its temperature will not increase beyond its boiling point unless all the water has converted to vapour. This extra energy provided is used in converting water to vapour at the same temperature and is called latent heat of vaporization.

So as long as you keep the temperature above the boiling point of sea water it will keep evaporating. The more you keep the temperature above the boiling point the faster the vaporization will take place. This also means you will need energy equivalent of (total mass of water in oceans) * (latent heat of vaporisation of water).